# Import a Javascript file into a REPL session

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I'm on Windows 10 TP build 9926, using nodejs. I want to be able to import a Javascript into a current session of nodejs that is running on Windows command prompt so that functions from the imported script can be called from within the REPL. How can I achieve that? My attempt of "import" and "require" did not succeed.

I tried the following in a nodejs session running from the directory that has the "learn.js" javascript;

```
var n = require("learn.js")
```

Then got the following error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'learn.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at repl:1:9
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:132:27)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
```

Comment: How did you use `require`? Please show us a log of your session so we can tell you what went wrong.

Comment: If you're `require`ing a CommonJS file then everything should work fine. `require`ing JS file written for web browser won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The learn.js file needs to look like the following:

```
"use strict";

module.exports.myfunc1 = function() {
    console.log("Hi there.");
}

module.exports.myfunc2 = function() {
    console.log("Goodbye.");
}
```

Also, you must require it like this:

```
var n = require('./learn.js');
```

or

```
var n = require('./learn');
```

You must make the path relative to where you are running the REPL.  Node won't automatically check the local directory.